autodesk-forge rotate 2d model instance by modifying VertexBufferReader array
I have tried successfully moving model elements in 2d using this blog https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/move-entities-2d-drawing
but when trying using the same method to rotate elements in 2d, weird behavior occurred
Original element:

Rotated element:

VBR.prototype.rotateLine = function (vindex, layer, vpId, angle, center) {
    var baseOffset = this.stride * vindex;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        const point = new THREE.Vector3(
            this.vbf[baseOffset + i * this.stride],
            this.vbf[baseOffset + i * this.stride + 1],
            0,
        );
        const rotated = RotatePoint(point, center, angle);

        this.vbf[baseOffset + i * this.stride] = rotated.x;
        this.vbf[baseOffset + i * this.stride + 1] = rotated.y;
        this.vbf[baseOffset + i * this.stride + 2] += 0.5;
        i++;
    }
};
function RotatePoint(point, around, angle)
{
    var start = new THREE.Vector3(point.x - around.x, point.y - around.y);
    point.x = Math.cos(angle) * start.x - Math.sin(angle) * start.y + around.x;
    point.y = Math.sin(angle) * start.x + Math.cos(angle) * start.y + around.y;
    return point;
}


maybe you can add some screenshots to make your question clearer.

@FakhrulIslamFuad already added 2 screenshots for original element and rotated element

Dint notice that earlier..

a quick glance.  The line objects appear to twist and split apart.  My guess is the origin point of the rotation is off.
